# verifiy twilio caller ID

Tags: twilio

I have twilio account and it is upgraded.I have IOS application where from customers number the call will be send to many number so it mandiate to verify the number of the user?  and if Yes could any one please let me know if there is any automatic verification process to verify that number without disturbing the customer  to verify manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can verify caller ids via the REST API using the [Outgoing Caller IDs resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list-post).

Essentially you make a POST request to that endpoint with the number you want to verify. Twilio will respond with a code that you need to show the user. Twilio will also initiate a call to that phone number asking for the user to enter the code. Once they have done so correctly, the number will be verified.

Comment: is it mandiat to verify caller id because If I have 1000 users then all those users need to verify right?.do we have automatic validation with sending the call or SMS?

Comment: If you want to verify the users in order to use their number as a caller then there needs to be a step in which the user interacts with and agrees to that verification. If you read through the process I described and linked to, you'll see that's as automatic as it can get.